# How can I enable or change column sort options in TFS2015 backlogs?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

The default views for backlogs in TFS 2015 online don't enable column sorting. As best I can tell, they're sorted by stack rank with no options to change or resort.

Ideally I'd like to enable user sorting in the template. If that's not possible, I'll settle for changing the default option to something else - essentially I want to be able to quickly separate tasks by State, which would be easy if I could sort by that column.

Bonus points if you can tell me how I can stop TFS from inserting its own random Stack Rank when people drag and drop things in the view!

Comment: I don't understand what your end goal is. Columns already map to a specific state. Everything in a given column is in the same state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of the backlog view is to show you a prioritised list of your work and by auto-setting the (now hidden) Stack Rank field, it means you don't have to fill it in.

You'll need to use a Work Item Query if you want to sort by another field.
If you click on the Backlog and then hit "Create Query" it will generate a query for you that is identical to the one used for the backlog.  You can then edit the query and change the sort order easily (then make it  a shared query and pin to your dashboard)

Another option is to use the filter on the backlog view (eg. Type "Approved") to show just items in a certain state.

Comment: Thanks. I thought stack rank was supposed to be set by the product owner and used as a priority field in sprint planning - i.e. not something a developer should edit?

Comment: Ideally, get your PO using TFS and then they can scope items to releases, ensure you have enough maintained items to fill a few sprints and then can drag and drop to re-prioritise.